# Split elements equally inside div

Tags: angular, center, justify

I am completely stuck. What I am trying basically to do :
I want to split elements inside div equally and justified that first element on the line would be next to left side and last element on the line would be next to the right side. If there is more elements it should go to the next line and repeat the process. Below is an example   ->

```
{A | B | C | D}
{E | K
```

My code: HTML:

```
<div class="webso-products">
    <div [ngClass]="'ui card webso-card'" *ngFor="let product of allProducts">
        <app-product></app-product>
    </div>
</div>
```

My code CSS:

```
.webso-products {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: justify;
}

.webso-products .webso-card {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #1b2a47;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none; 
    padding: 1rem 1rem 0rem 1rem; 
}
```

***I tried*** using pseudo element : after (with width : 100% and display: inline-block), but somehow it does not work when using Angular iteration...

Really appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just do ?

```
<div class="webso-products">
    <div [ngClass]="'ui card webso-card'" *ngFor="let product of allProducts">
        <div class="webso-card-product">
            <app-product></app-product>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.webso-card{display:flex; flex-direction:row}
.webso-card-product{width=25%}
@media #{...} {
    .webso-card-product{width=...}
}
```

Comment: Not really the thing is that design should be responsive and in some cases it would fit 4 elements, sometimes 3 or 2. I hope you get the point.

Comment: @user2149578 I have updated the answer to be reponsive. A question: Do you want 4 elements for each row or do you want dynamic item number?

Comment: Hmm that could be a way most likely, but I am surprised if there is no easier work around for this situation (which I think is pretty common)...